# How to prevent SwiftUI Scrollview from bottlenecking performance of Canvas

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When using ScrollView and Canvas together, every scroll event by the scrollview causes a redraw, which is a heavy bottleneck on my view's performance, which utilizes a canvas for ~100x100 grid. Is there a way to prevent, or at least *mitigate* this constant redrawing for better canvas scrolling performance? It looks somewhat choppy when scrolling on very complicated canvas views, which doesn't happen in HTML.

This behavior seems to only happen with large canvases, as a ScrollView with many small Canvases do not replicate this same behavior of constant redrawing.

Here is a simple example showing that ScrollView causes lots of redraws:

```swift
import SwiftUI
var i = 0
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {       
            Canvas { _, _ in
                i = i+1
                print(i)
                
            }.background(.red).frame(width: 2000, height: 2000, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

I need a solution that works with iOS 15, as I am developing for older devices.

Comment: How about using an `Image` instead? e.g. `Image(size: .init(width: 2000, height: 2000)) { ... }`. It doesn't support all the features of `Canvas` (e.g. resolving `Symbol`s), but if all you need is a `GraphicsContext`, you could try it. The drawing closure isn't called on scrolling.

Comment: @Sweeper I need my application to work with iOS 15; it's not possible to use that constructor with iOS 15.